# Is there a way to make multiple things drop at once?

Tags: python

I'm new to python and wanted to try make a game but I don't know how to make multiple objects drop at once. This is a text based game because I'm learning with Grok and haven't gotten up to that question. I just made this small game to challenge myself but I've been scratching my head for the past hour.

The game is a simple game about dodging the objects and every time you move the objects come one line closer. If you get hit by one you restart. Every time a object hits the ground your score goes up by one.

I originally tried to queue them but that didn't work and now I don't know what to do. If you could make it more optimized that would also help.

This is the code:

```py
import random
# Sets up Board
grid = []
x = 1
cx = random.randrange(3)
cy = 0
for i in range(4):
  row = []
  for j in range(3):
    row.append('.')
  grid.append(row)
for k in range(3):
  grid[3][k] = '='
grid[2][x] = 'x'
grid[cy][cx] = 'c'
# Draws Board
for row in grid:
  print(''.join(row))
# Movement (Left or Right)
d = input('a or d? ')
while d:
  dx = x
  cdy = cy
  if d == 'a':
    x -= 1
    if x < 0:
      x += 1
  if d == 'd':
    x += 1
    if x > 2:
      x -= 1
  cy += 1 # Makes objects come closer
# Checks if objects are touching floor and if so creates new object at random column
  if cy > 2:
    cy = 0
    grid[cdy][cx] = '.'
    cx = random.randrange(3)
# Ends game if player gets hit by object
  if cx == x and cy == 2:
    if x != dx:
      grid[2][dx] = '.'
    grid[cdy][cx] = '.'
    grid[2][x] = 'x'
    grid[cy][cx] = 'c'
    for row in grid:
      print(''.join(row))
    print('You got hit by a car :(')
    break
  if x != dx:
    grid[2][dx] = '.'
  grid[cdy][cx] = '.'
  grid[2][x] = 'x'
  grid[cy][cx] = 'c'
  for row in grid:
    print(''.join(row))
  d = input('a or d? ')
```

The board looks something like this but you can add more rows:

```py
.c.
...
.x.
===
```

`x` = player
`c` = object

I want the board to look more like this and to add more random objects as the first objects hit the floor:

```py
..c
...
.c.
...
c..
...
.c.
.x.
===
```

Every time the player moves left or right the objects(c) move down by one row. The objects when they hit the ground would delete and a new object which is in a random spot of 1, 2 or 3 is placed in the air.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), a more detailed explanation of the game and your problem, and what you've tried so far.

Comment: That code is nearly unreadable. Please use meaningful names for your variables and use an indentation of 4 spaces per level.

Comment: A plain text description of what the code is trying to do and what the problem is would help greatly.  No one knows what "dropping multiple cars" even means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use the `random.sample()` function to create multiple `y` values. After you generated them, place the cars initially into the playfield just like you do it with your single car right now. You could do that by looping over all `y` values that you randomly generated.